# Nodejs killed Sharp process by timeout 5 sec

Tags: javascript, sharp, fastify

I use sharp on Hook to resize images on the fly in fastify.

```
fastify.addHook('onSend', async (request, reply, payload) => {
          const newPayload = await sharp(payload.filename).resize(200, 100).toFormat('jpg').toBuffer();
         return newPayload
      })
```

But when I run this code

[image]

I see 5 seconds between finished resize and killed some process bu Nodejs at the end.

After it I get image into browser.

Can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: did you try the [stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp#stream) interface?
The 5 sec seems a timeout to me

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon maybe I did mistake with example.I get empty response. Anyway I added this functionality to route without hook and works very good. resizing works like without resizing. Yes. It is timeout. But I can understand why on hook I get timeout,

Comment: I think the content-length is not updated